# Recycle view did not show all the things

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

[image]

Every item I have an image and 3 data, as u can see the last part is not shown. The bottom navigate view has blocked some info, I need to show all it out.

Anyone help?

Here's my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Recycleview">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="530dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

        </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

it can scroll.

Comment: does it scroll?

Comment: Before you get some downvote, post all code of your layout.xml. As i cant see start of `RelativeLayout` and show your recycler view item layout also.

Comment: @Khemraj updated

Comment: @JoeyDalu it can scroll

Comment: Can not see item layout also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_circle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```